# Counting DNA codons in DNA file

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, awk

I want to create a bash script that takes in a dna file and checks that it has no newline characters or white space characters, and then outputs the unique codons along with their count of the number of times they occur. I have used the following code but the codon keeps giving me an output of "bash-3.2$". I am so confused as to whether my syntax is wrong and why I'm not getting the proper output.

```
! /bin/bash

for (( pos=1; pos < length - 1; ++pos )); do
    codon = substr($1, $pos, 3)
    tr-d '\n' $1 | awk -f '{print $codon}' | sort | uniq -c
done
```

For example if a file named dnafile contains the pattern aacacgaactttaacacg then the script will take the following input and output

```
 $script dnafile              
 aac 3
 acg 2
 ttt 1
```

Comment: You banged where you should've [shebanged](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10376206).

Comment: A few notes: i) you really, really don't want to do this sort of thing in the shell, especially not for large files. ii) you should probably look at some basic tutorials on shell scripting: there is no such thing as `substr`, you can't have spaces around the `=` in variable assignments, and your shebang is wrong.  iii) remember that there are 6 possible reading frames, are you sure you only need to look at one? iv) your dna file will almost never just have sequence in it, you usually have some sort of header and extra information (fasta, fastq, sam tec.)

Answer (score 9):

You get that output because the first line of your script starts a new `bash` shell.

That line should read

```
#!/bin/bash
```

(note the `#` at the start).

You then mix `awk` syntax with shell code in a way that will never work.

Instead, keep it simple and chop up your file in groups of three characters, sort these and count how many unique ones you get:

```
$ fold -w 3 dnafile | sort | uniq -c
   3 aac
   2 acg
   1 ttt
```

This would work as long as the input always contains a multiple of three characters, with no embedded spaces or other characters.

Comment: how would I check for spaces and if it contains a multiple of three characters?

Comment: @RajveerSingh You could _delete_ spaces and newlines etc. with `tr -d '\n ' <dnafile | fold -w 3 | sort | uniq -c`. If it's not a multiple of three characters in the file, there will be a short codon in the output.

Comment: when I use tr -d '\n ' <dnafile | fold -w 3 | sort | uniq -c, I get the following error:  tr [-Ccsu] string1 string2
       tr [-Ccu] -d string1
       tr [-Ccu] -s string1
       tr [-Ccu] -ds string1 string2.

Comment: @RajveerSingh There is nothing wrong with your command in your latest comment. In fact, I'm able to copy it from the comment and run it directly.

Comment: No need to sort: `fold -w 3 dna | perl -ne '$a{$_}++;END{print map {$a{$_}." ".$_} keys %a}'`

Answer (score 3):

```
(echo aacacgaactttaacacg ;echo aacacgaactttaacacg ) |
  perl -ne '# Split input into triplets (A3)
            # use each triplet as key in the hash table count
            #   and increase the value for the key
            map { $count{$_}++ } unpack("(A3)*",$_);
            # When we are at the end of the file
            END{ 
                 # Remove the key "" (which is wrong)
                 delete $count{""};
                 # For each key: Print key, count
                 print map { "$_ $count{$_}\n" } keys %count
            }'
```

Answer (score 1):

A slightly more long-winded `awk` version

```
awk 'BEGINFILE{print FILENAME; delete codon}
     ENDFILE {
     if (NR!=1 || NF!=1 || length($0)%3!=0){
         print "is broken"}
     else{
         for (i=1; i<=length($0); i+=3) codon[substr($0,i,3)]++}; 
         for (c in codon) print c, codon[c]; 
         print ""}' file*
```

For this input

file1 : OK

```
aacacgaactttaacacg
```

file2 : space

```
aacacgaact ttaacacg
```

file3 : linebreak

```
aacacgaact
ttaacacg
```

file4 : not a multiple of 3 bases

```
aacacgaactttaacac
```

You get

```
file1
aac 3
ttt 1
acg 2

file2
is broken

file3
is broken

file4
is broken
```

If you just want to repair the files and have none like `file4` then `cat` your files through `tr` from one end of `awk` or the other, just like your example

```
<<< $(cat file[1..3] | tr -d "\n ")
```